# C++ polymorphism use child constructor

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want to use child class constructor when parent object was given to a function.

```
class foo {
public:
    virtual void doThing() { };
};

class bar : public foo {
public:
    void doThing() override;
};

class bar2 : public foo {
public:
    void doThing() override;
};

int main () {
    bar obj;
    bar2 obj2;
    someFunction(&obj);
    someFunction(&obj2);
}

void someFunction(foo *obj) {
   //child object construction
}
```

If `bar` class object pointer was passed to a `someFunction()` then it would create new `bar` object inside function. Same thing with `bar2` class and so on.

My question: is there a way to construct a child object when object's reference was given?

Comment: http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/

Comment: or if you don't want to go all the way to using the CRTP, you provide a pure virtual "clone" method in foo, and then define it in the members. But you've got other problems with your code. doThing should always be virtual, your base class should probably be pure virtual, ect.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the clonable pattern shows up a lot in software design. Its useful all the time...it is really the only way to say, make a copy of a collection of polymorphic objects.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Yup, I completely misread this.  Thought it was asking to create a child object given a parent object.

Comment: @MariusMiskinis rolled as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way you do this is to provide a pure virtual "clone" method in foo, and then define it in the members.

The particularly good designers (A good designer is a lazy designer) use the Curiously Recursing Template Pattern (CRTP) to help this out.

```
class foo { public: virtual foo* clone() const=0; virtual ~foo(){}}
template <typename Derived>
class foo_helper : public foo
{
public:
   virtual foo* clone() const
   {
     return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
   }
   virtual ~foo_helper(){}
}
class Bar : foo_helper<Bar>
{
public:
   virtual ~Bar(){}
}
```

see also:
http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/